# .NET MAUI localhost API running out of runtime exception in android

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, mobile-application

I am trying to fetch a localhost api in a mobile application built using .NET MAUI

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace LocalApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Button Clicked", "response", "Ok");

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var url = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android
                                ? "http://10.0.2.2:5214/weatherforecast"
                                : "http://localhost:5214/weatherforecast";

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            try
            {

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    api.Text = content;
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Wrong status code", "ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LocalApp/Platforms/MainApplication.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace LocalApp
{
    [Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
    public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
            : base(handle, ownership)
        {
        }
        
        protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    }
}
```

for debugging purposes I have set UsesCleartextTraffic to true!

Also the application works well on Windows platform but run out of a runtime exception on android.

Help appreciated

Comment: Well what goes wrong? You did not mention any error in your post

Comment: What is the exact exception message ? or inner exception message ?

Comment: The error says, in a toast that the app is experiencing some runtime exception , also after debugging i found that the httpClient is also generating null response

Comment: @ShubhankarPande is this really what the toast says? "the app is experiencing some runtime exception"? Very strange indeed...

Comment: yeah! I am completely confused!

Comment: What is the actual value of the exception object?

Comment: @ShubhankarPande I know you say you allowed http traffic, but just to be sure, can you show your network_security_config.xml file, and the manifest?

Comment: @H.A.H. Please check this stackoverflow post where I have added the network_security_config.xml file and I have also changed the manifest file.
Thanks in advance!